# How to find sequence with identical name in two very large fasta file and join them with a gap?

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I have two very large fasta file, both are around 2GB. They have some sequences share same name, so it is like:

in R1.fasta:

">ABC001 ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC003
ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC005
ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC010
ACTGTGTCGTG

and in R2.fasta

">ABC002
ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC003
ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC005
ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC009
ACTGTGTCGTG

I want to find the shared sequences between the two files, can write to a new fasta file and join the two sequences with a gap, so the new file would look like:

">ABC003
ACTGTGTCGTG-----ACTGTGTCGTG

">ABC005
ACTGTGTCGTG-----ACTGTGTCGTG

I have wrote a python script to do this job, but it ran extremely slow. I wonder if there is a faster way to do this. Thanks! the code is like:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

R1 = 'L008_R1.forward.trim.fasta' #input R1 file
R2 = 'L008_R2.reverse.trim.fasta' # input R2 file
R  = 'Gap20.L008.R1.fasta' #output joined fasta

n1 = 0
n2 = 0

for rec1 in SeqIO.parse(R1, 'fasta'): #exam every record in R1 file one by one
    n1 = int(rec1.id[5:]) 
    r = rec1 
    for rec2 in SeqIO.parse(R2,'fasta'): 
        n2 = int(rec2.id[5:]) 
        if n1 == n2: 
            seq = rec1.seq+'--------------------'+rec2.seq 
            r.seq = seq 
            output =  open(R, 'aw') # write to a new fasta file
            SeqIO.write(r, output, 'fasta')
            break
        elif n1 < n2: 
    else: pass
```

Comment: Do the rows in the files are sorted by ids? If so, there's another solution that's faster still than the one I already posted

Answer (score 2):

You should use [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

The bottleneck in your solution is comparing every pair of records from the two files for names.

A better solution is to store all the records from the first file, then for each row in the second file find out if a record of the same name was found in the first file and concatenate them if that's the case.

A dict stores pairs of data: a "key" and a "value"; and allows quick (`O(n log n)`) insertion of such pairs and quick lookups, by the key. In your case, the record names would serve as the keys and the sequences as the values.

It would roughly (untested) look like:

```
# Assuming that record id's are unique within a single file

records = dict()
output = open(R, 'aw')
for record in SeqIO.parse(R1, 'fasta'):
    record_id = int(rec.id[5:])
    records[record_id] = rec1.seq

for record in SeqIO.parse(R2, 'fasta'):
    record_id = int(rec2.id[5:])
    if record_id in records:
        r = records[record_id]
        r.seq = r.seq + '--------------------' + record.seq
    else:
        r = record
    SeqIO.write(r, output, 'fasta')
```